# Pandas rows containing numpy ndarrays various shapes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, ragged, ragged-tensors

I'd creating a Pandas DataFrame in which each particular `(index, column)` location can be a numpy ndarray of arbitrary shape, or even a simple number.

This works:

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
x = pd.DataFrame([[np.random.rand(100, 100, 20, 2), 3], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4]],
                              index=['A1', 'B2', 'C3', 'D4'], columns=['data', 'data2'])
print(x)
```

but takes 50 seconds to create on my computer! Why?

`np.random.rand(100, 100, 20, 2)` alone is super fast (< 1 second to create)

**How to speed up the creation of Pandas datasets containing ndarrays of various shapes?**

Comment: When a pandas DataFrame is a homogenous type, the whole thing can be a single numpy array.  When you create a list like this where the columns are hetergeneous, pandas has to do a bunch of bookkeeping and reformatting to keep track of the different datatypes.

Comment: Yes probably @TimRoberts but here I only have ~400 000 coefficients to store in the dataframe. 50 seconds for this is really problematic! Is there an easy fix here?

Comment: It's not the creation taking time, it's the `print`. The creation is pretty much instantaneous on my computer, as is `print(x['data2'])`. But `print(x['data'])` takes about 15 seconds

Comment: Oh you're right @Nick, solved! You can post as an answer!

Comment: In fact `print(x['data']['A1'])` and `print(x['data']['B2'])` are likewise super fast. So I guess `print` is just having trouble putting together elements of vastly different size. A bug perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not actually the creation that is the issue, it's the `print` statement. 1000 loops of the creation take 2.8 seconds on my computer. But one iteration of the `print` takes about 26 seconds.

Interestingly, `print(x['data2'])`, `print(x['data']['A1'])` and `print(x['data']['B2'])` are all basically instantaneous. So it seems `print` is having an issue figuring out how to display items of vastly different size. Perhaps a bug?